# Java - Does the package statement is removed in .class file?

Tags: java, javac

As we know that the `package` statement is when triggered by the `javac` command, it creates the related directories according to the package name.

**For example:**

```
// MyClassB.java
package abc.xyz;

class MyClassA{
  // ...
}

class MyClassB{
  // ...
}
```

Now when I compile this file:

```
javac -d . MyClassB.java
```

After compilation, we will have the following directory structure having the `.class` files.

```
/
 |___ abc
    |___ xyz
        |___ MyClassA.class
        |___ MyClassB.class
```

Now the question is that, are these `MyClassA.class` and `MyClassB.class` contains only the `MyClassA` and `MyClassB` class's compiled bytecode?

**What about the following statement?**

```
package abc.xyz;
```

Is that statement removed during the compilation? Or this statement is only removed from the `MyClassA` class and remains in the `MyClassB` class because the name of the file was `MyClassB.java`. Or maybe the `MyClassB.class` file only contains the `MyClassB` class bytecode after compilation and the `package abc.xyz;` is removed during the compilation as well? If `package abc.xyz;` is not removed at the compilation time then it would be the problem when we will use this file at runtime because the runtime engine will also trigger the `package abc.xyz;` statement bytecode version, so, it would be a problem. Or it is removed during the compilation? Or the bytecode is only created for the classes but not for the file which contains the `package abc.xyz;` statement which results that `package abc.xyz;` is not become the part of the `.class` files.

**The picture below clearly explains the question:**
[image]

Can anyone explain what is the scenario behind this? It is my humble request to the contributors to not negative mark my question because i have some confusions regarding java, so, i want to clear my concept.If still my question is able for negative mark, then its Ok do, but at least answer as well.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Please could you clarify this sentence? " If package abc.xyz; is not removed at the compilation time then it would be the problem when we will use this file at runtime because the runtime engine will also trigger the package abc.xyz; statement bytecode version, so, it would be a problem." What do you mean by "trigger package abc.xyz statement bytecode version"?

Comment: I mean that the objective of `package abc.xyz;` statement is to create directories and place the `.class` files inside the `xyz` directory, so, the run time will do the same job as the compile time? So, is this not the problem? Because the runtime will say lets create directories because of the `package abc.xyz;` statement, so, this is my understanding, now i don't know what is the scene behind.

Comment: Let says i have a statement `System.out.print("Hello world");`. Now when this program runs the `Hello World` will be printed, right? So lets say i have `package abc.xyz;` statement, Now when this program runs will it again create the directories and .class files? i hope you got me now!!! I am talking about runtime Ok.

Comment: No, it's the *compilation* process that creates class files. That's entirely separate from what happens when you run the code.

Comment: "I mean that the objective of package abc.xyz; statement is to create directories and place the .class files inside the xyz directory" - no, it's to specify the package for the classes declared in that source file. It's not "code that runs". It's the compiler that decides what it should do with class files. A different compile might not use the file system at all, but it would still need to know the package of a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directives like the `package` declaration, as well as `import` statements, do not generate any code at all, they only affect how the compiler will treat names within the same compilation unit.

So a declaration like

```
package abc.xyz;

public class MyClassA {

}
```

creates a class with the qualified name `abc.xyz.MyClassA` or a class with the simple name `MyClassA` within the package `abc.xyz`; both means the same.

**The qualified name is stored within the `.class` file, which is the only relevant information to the JVM.**

There is the *convention* to store such file as `SimpleName.class` within a directory derived from the package name, i.e. `abc/xyz/MyClassA.class`, adhered by `javac` and used by the standard class loaders to look up the file when a class of that name is requested. Obviously, having such a convention makes life easier.

In principle, other storage methods are possible and there are some known. Starting with Java 9, the reference implementation has a module image format, before that, there was the “shared class data archive”, further, there was “Pack200”, an archive format that has been deprecated for removal with JDK 11.

Note that even jar files, which are extended zip files, are not exactly what you see. A zip file consist of a linear sequence of file entries having a qualified name, so in your case, you would have two entries reporting their names as `abc/xyz/MyClassA.class` and `abc/xyz/MyClassB.class`, whereas any directory structure shown by tools is actually derived from these names and does not implies that nested entries for `abc` and `xyz` actually exist. Still, the standard class loader will also use these entries the same way as if this directory structure existed, so there is no problem with the mindset of having stored the directory structure into the zip/jar file.

But starting with Java 9, there can be different versions for the same class, to be selected depending on the current Java version. The naming scheme used for that is not part of the convention used by javac when storing the files.

Comment: really? the jar files structure might not exist and such folder structure is derived from the actual name?

Comment: @Eugene the zip file entry’s name, not necessarily the actual class name. This means, you can create a zip file, e.g. via `ZipOutputStream`, create a single entry via `putNextEntry` with the name `foo/bar/baz`, and when you open it with the zip file system or a similar file system oriented tool, it will show you a `foo` directory, containing a `bar` directory, containing a `baz` file, whereas the zip file has only one single entry. Normally, zip files do not contain entries for directories at all.

Answer (score 2):

It does not *go* anywhere, it is compiled as `class abc.xyz.MyClassA`. You can see that if you would decompile that `.class` for example using `javap`.

Comment: But the result of the `package abc.xyz;` statement is to create the directories and place the `.class` file in the directory. So, whether the run time will also create the directory again and again when this program runs, is this not a problem? or `package abc.xyz;` statement is not executed in runtime?

Comment: Let says i have a statement `System.out.print("Hello world");`. Now when this program runs the `Hello World` will be printed, right? So lets say i have `package abc.xyz;` statement, Now when this program runs will it again create the directories and .class files? i hope you got me now!!! I am talking about runtime Ok.

Comment: @SunnyKhan "runtime runs" already compiled classes, it does not compile them again. you do understand that right?

Comment: So, the `package abc.xyz;` is not the part of runtime?

Comment: **Part1** "_But the result of the package abc.xyz; statement is to create the directories_" no the statement `package abc.xyz:` only checks if you are in the right directory if you are not the compiler or ide text editor will say something like _the package name doesn't mach with the name of the directory_ again  `package abc.xyz:`creates NOTHING it is like cast --> lets say class dog extends class animal you can write something like Animal a = new Dog(); and then you could write Dog d = (Dog) a; if a would be some other animal like a=new Cat(); you would get compile time error

Comment: **Part2** cast doesn't change the object it doesnt turn a into Dog its similar with package its only there to check if your file is in the right directory

Answer (score 1):

If you open the .class file of any of your class than you can see the package details inside that. In your case if you will open `MyClassA.class` in text editor, then you can see something like `abc/xyz/MyClassA`. The the JVM will use it like `abc.xyz.MyClassA`. That's the reason if we need to use this class in some other class, we need to use it like `import abc.xyz.MyClassA`.

Comment: Let says i have a statement `System.out.print("Hello world");`. Now when this program runs the `Hello World` will be printed, right? So lets say i have `package abc.xyz;` statement, Now when this program runs will it again create the directories and .class files? i hope you got me now!!! I am talking about runtime Ok.

Comment: Package is used for grouping java types (classes, interfaces, enums etc). So when you use the package in your java program it bind those java types in one package.

Comment: Please read this from oracle for more details information. [Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)